# Hive - Update From statement with a inline query

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, teradata

I have the following query and I wanted to run it in Hive but Hive does not support inline queries in update. Can anyone please help me with this update query in Hive?

```
UPDATE TABLE1 FROM 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS NEW_COUNT
   FROM TABLE2
   WHERE XTRCT_DT IN (SELECT MAX(XTRCT_DT) FROM TABLE3)) AS T
SET TBL = T.NEW_COUNT
WHERE XTRCT_DT IN(SELECT MAX(XTRCT_DT) FROM TABLE4)  AND TN=1;
```

Currently I am using hive version Above 3.0.

I have tried Merge statement for this update but it didn't worked. Can someone please help?

This was the MERGE statement that I tried working but I was getting an error in ON clause for inclusion of IN.

```
    MERGE INTO TABLE1 USING (
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NEW_COUNT FROM TABLE2 WHERE XTRCT_DT IN(SELECT MAX(XTRCT_DT) FROM TABLE3)) AS T
ON XTRCT_DT IN(SELECT MAX(XTRCT_DT) FROM TABLE4)  AND TN=1
SET TBL=T.NEW_COUNT;
```

Comment: MERGE seems like the correct approach. Show the MERGE that did not work.

Comment: I have added the Merge statement that I have worked on too. Please check and get back with a solution please

Answer (score 0):

Your `MERGE` is missing a `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE` clause and also does not have a join condition between the source subquery T and the target TABLE1. Move the filter date into the source subquery and use that to join:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE1
 USING (SELECT COUNT(*) AS NEW_COUNT,
   (SELECT MAX(XTRCT_DT) FROM TABLE4) AS MATCH_DT
   FROM TABLE2
   WHERE XTRCT_DT IN (SELECT MAX(XTRCT_DT) FROM TABLE3)
   ) AS T
ON XTRCT_DT = T.MATCH_DT AND TN=1
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET TBL=T.NEW_COUNT;
```

You could instead cross-join (JOIN with no ON clause) the subquery for MATCH_DT with TABLE2 rather than using a scalar subquery in the `SELECT` list.